# Format a SQL/PHP generated table

Tags: php, html, sql

I am clueless on how to format this generated table the way I want:

```
<?php
$dbQuery=$db->prepare("select distinct tracks.title, albums.title, artists.name, basket.id ".
                      "from basket,tracks,albums,artists ".
                      "where basket.userID=:userID ".
                      "and basket.paid='Y' ".
                      "and basket.trackID=tracks.id ".
                      "and albums.id=tracks.albumID ".
                      "and artists.id=tracks.artistID".
                      " order by artists.name, albums.title, tracks.title, basket.id");


$dbParams = array('userID'=>$_SESSION["currentUserID"]);                      
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
$numTracks=$dbQuery->rowCount();

if ($numTracks==0)
   echo "<h3>You have not made any purchases</h3>";
else {

?>

   <h2>Your Purchase History</h2>

   <table style="margin-left:15px" id="test">
   <tr><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th><th>Track</th></tr>

<?php 

   while ($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {

      echo "<tr><td>$dbRow[2]</td><td>$dbRow[1]</td><td>$dbRow[0]</td><td>$dbRow[3]</td></tr>";
   }
}
?>

</table>
```

Basically this will generate duplicate values from the fields, artists and album. I need to merge the duplicate ones so instead of multiple of the same of artist/album in a column they are merged into one cell

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Artist1</th>
    <th>ablum1</th>
    <th>song1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Artist1</td>
    <td>ablum2</td>
    <td>song1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Artist2</td>
    <td>ablum1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

This instead of above

<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Artist1</th>
    <th>ablum1</th>
    <th>song1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ablum2</td>
    <td>song1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Artist2</td>
    <td>ablum1</td>
    <td>song1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript doesn't seem to work, as the table is generated after the page loads I think.

Comment: format your sample data and desired output to understand you well

Comment: what is your RDBMS? is it MySQL?

Comment: Using PHPMyAdmin with MySQL